# Update existing EntityCollection in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository

I'm trying to resolve the problem in EF to update a collection in my entity:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeveEditarUsuarioNoRepositorio()
{
    Usuario usuario = _usuarioRepository.GetById(1);

    usuario.Nome = "Samla Peidorreira";
    usuario.Email = "samlapeidanascalca@samlapeidanascalca.com";
    usuario.DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 11, 19, 4, 23, 54, 0);
    usuario.Sexo = (Sexo)Convert.ToByte(Sexo.Masculino);
    usuario.Telefone = null;
    usuario.Credencial.Status = (Status)Convert.ToByte(Status.Ativo);

    //That's the collection I want to update
    usuario.Credencial.Perfis = new List<Perfil>() { new Perfil() { Nome = "Fotografos", DataEdicao = new DateTime(1996, 2, 1, 12, 15, 42, 27), Deletado = true, Status = false, Tipo = 3 } };

    usuario.Credencial.NomeUsuario = "samlapeidanascalca";
    usuario.Credencial.Senha = "samlacagona";

    _usuarioRepository.Edit(usuario);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    Usuario usuarioEditado = _usuarioRepository.GetById(1);

    Assert.AreEqual("Samla Peidorreira", usuarioEditado.Nome);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlapeidanascalca@samlapeidanascalca.com", usuarioEditado.Email);
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1988, 11, 19, 4, 23, 54, 0), usuarioEditado.DataNascimento);
    Assert.AreEqual(Sexo.Masculino, usuarioEditado.Sexo);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, usuarioEditado.Telefone);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Ativo, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Perfis.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Perfis[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlapeidanascalca", usuarioEditado.Credencial.NomeUsuario);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlacagona", usuarioEditado.Credencial.Senha);
}
```

What happen is when i set `Perfis` Property for a new List, it not replace the value in property, it add the values of that new List in the actual List in that property. **WTF WHY this is happen?**

What I do to resolve this is doing this in my entity:

```
public class Credencial : Entity
{
    private IList<Perfil> _perfis;

    public Credencial()
    {
        Status = Status.Inativo;
    }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Perfil> Perfis
    {
        get { return _perfis ?? (_perfis = new List<Perfil>()); }
        set { Perfis.Clear(); _perfis = value; }
    }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public byte StatusId
    {
        get { return (byte)Status; }
        set { Status = (Status)value; }
    }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }

    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

LOOK AT MY **SET{}** IN `Perfis` Property. Doing that even when i want to Set the `Perfis` property, it will clear the list and add the new List with new Itens.

I'm doing something wrong? Nobody talks about this solution.

Comment: What is the point of your question? How will the clearing list help to solve you the problem?

Comment: @Ladislav Before when I send a new object, it only adds the items of this object. Now it clears the list and add.

Comment: And what should it do? It does exactly what you instruct it to do.

Comment: @Ladislav No, when i replace the Collection in my Entity, it add the itens in that new collection, it not replace the actual collection.

Comment: Sure it doesn't. The collection itself has no relation to the entity state. By replacing collection you did nothing. I wrote you in your previous question that you must manually set states of related entities. There is no hidden magic which will do this for you (actually there is but it would require completely different approach and mostly abandoning repository pattern).

Comment: @Ladislav but look what I do. I clear the itens in my Property and attach a new object in that Property. Now when I add a new List in my Property, this new list is OK, all previous itens is removed from my list. Do you understand?

Comment: I understand but you don't. Assigning new list has nothing to do with attaching entity. The result is still the same. Moreover EF didn't know about previous list (or it was empty) otherwise you would most probably get an exception.

Comment: @Ladislav No, I don't get exception. Clearing the list before to replace that my problem was resolved, now the previous list is clear and the new object works normally, I'm trying to understand with you this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Now I understand your problem. I thought you want to update relations but you want to replace them and still keep the old objects. I expect that `Usuario` and `Perfil` are in many-to-many relation, aren't they?

If you only replace the list the old values still exists. EF will do nothing to remove them because replacing collection deoesn't affect them but if you instead call the clear on the list it delete relations between current `Usuario` and all loaded `Perfil` (it will remove records from junction table during `SaveChanges`).

I think that you should not clear the list in the entity's setter. You should even not allow to change the collection. You should call the clear in your test logic and then add a new `Perfil`:

```
usuario.Credencial.Perfis.Clear();
usuario.Credencial.Perfis.Add(new Perfil { ... });
```

The reason is that EF sometimes doesn't like if you manipulate collections for navigation properties and it fires exceptions that initialized collection cannot be assigned.

Comment: this example I'm update a existing item in my list. I don't want this. What I want is to replace my list with new list of NEW ITENS. The itens in previous list will continue to exist.

Comment: Yes, this is What I do. I Clear the list even before to Set a new object in that property, look at my SET, what you think?